# Android NavigationBar Alternative Approach for Devices with Smaller Screens

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, navigation-android

I need to provide an alternative NavigationBar implementation should the device's width be less that 600.

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
val config = LocalConfiguration.current

    val useBottomNavigation by remember {
        derivedStateOf { config.smallestScreenWidthDp < 600 }
    }

    Scaffold(bottomBar = {

        if (useBottomNavigation) {
               // call NavigationBar composable
               BottomNavigationBar()
            }
            else{
               Spacer(
                    Modifier.navigationBarsHeight()
                            .fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
```

However, **`modifier.navigationBarsHeight()`** call is not being resolved.
[image]

I am on `Compose Version 1.5.1` and `Material3 1.2.0-alpha03`.

Anyone with an idea on how to go about this in compose please do help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Migration Table](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#migration-table), what used to be `Modifier.navigationBarsHeight()` in Accompanist is now `Modifier.windowInsetsBottomHeight(WindowInsets.navigationBars)` in androidx.compose.foundation. The doc on the latter is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).windowInsetsBottomHeight(androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets)).

Comment: Thx lots Poet, it worked!